# Set photo as marker in map

Tags: android

Let's say I got the absolute path into the photo. /mnt/sdcard/....jpg

```
   String path = "/mnt/sdcard/....jpg";
   BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(), path);
   d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());

   overlayItem.setMarker(d);
```

This is what i tried, however the photo does not display.

EDIT: fixed, wrong path to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
```

Ok, and what about this:

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
```

Comment: Drawable.createFromPath(path); seems return null.

Comment: Maybe, you should try methods: `invalidateSelf()` or `setVisible(true, true)`. Kenyi, what returns methods `d.getIntrinsicWidth()` and `d.getIntrinsicHeight()`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code?
The way Pasha said should work.
Let's say you have an image in you drawable folder named your_image, you could do like this:

```
        Point point = new Point();
        yourMapView.getProjection().toPixels(yourGeoPoint, point);

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.your_image);            
        yourCanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, point.x, point.y-(your_size), null);
```